# Proof that a limit is true

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

In my assignment I have to prove the following limit, by definition:

$$\lim _{x \to 2}\sqrt{3x-2}=2 $$

I have made some calculations trying to prove it, and I've made some way but I'm afraid I'm wrong somewhere. Your help is needed, please.

$$|\sqrt{3x-2}-2|$$  $$=\frac{|(\sqrt{3x-2}|-2)*|(\sqrt{3x-2}+2)}{\sqrt{3x-2}+2}$$  $$=\frac{|3x-6|}{\sqrt{3x-2}+2}$$ $$=\frac{3|x-2|}{\sqrt{3x-2}+2}<\frac{3|x-2|}{\frac{1}{3}}=9*|x-2|$$

Now we choose $$\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{9}$$

And say that $$9*|x-2|<\delta$$
$$|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{9}<\epsilon$$

And we proved what's needed.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Looks fine. $\frac{3|x-2|}{\sqrt{3x-2}+2}\le\frac{3|x-2|}{2}$ might be simpler... Take care with your $\le$ and $<$.

Comment: I might be able, but is my solution not correct? didn't try it for the value 2.

Comment: Your solution is correct. @Alan , but do you know why you have a $\frac{1}{3}$ there?

Comment: The solution is fine, except for you are a little sloppy with $\le$ vs $<$. For example, if $x=2$, the above reads $0<0$ which is false.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you very much, I will take care of these issues.

Comment: @John I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: So I guess you understand you are using $\sqrt{3x-2} + 2 > \frac 13$ in your solution. But as copper hat observed, $\sqrt{3x-2} +2 >2$ would be another (more natural?) inequality to use.

Comment: There is a small technical hitch.  We are supposed to find, given any $\epsilon$, a suitable $\delta$. Suppose that we are given $\epsilon=1000$ (I know, silly). Then your inequality seems to say that an appropriate value is $\delta=1000/9$. But for many $x$ within $1000/9$ of $2$, the expression $\sqrt{3x-2}$ isnot even defined. The fix is easy. Let $\delta$ be the smaller of $1$ and $\epsilon/9$.